# Weak equivalences in $\text{Top}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, model-categories

Weak equivalences in $\text{Top}$ are the ones for which is
$$\pi_n(f,x)$$ a bijection or more strictly group isomorphism ?
See the definition $2.4.3.$ in the snippet below.
I understand that
$\pi_0(X,x)$ is a set but $\pi_n(X,x)$ for $n\geq 1$ is a group.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for $n>0$, $\pi_n(f,x)$ is always a homomorphism, so it is an isomorphism iff it is a bijection.  For $n=0$, $\pi_0(X,x)$ has only the structure of a pointed set, not a group, so to say that $\pi_0(f,x)$ is an isomorphism would just be that it is an isomorphism of pointed sets, which just means it is a bijection which preserves the basepoint.  So, if you like, you can just interpret "isomorphism" to always mean "bijection" in this definition.

Actually, though, the definition is wrong: when $X$ is empty, the definition would say that any map $f:X\to Y$ is a weak equivalence vacuously (since there are no choices of $x\in X$).  The correct definition is:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map in $\mathbf{Top}$.  Then $f$ is a weak equivalence if:
>
> - $\pi_0(f):\pi_0(X)\to\pi_0(Y)$ is a bijection, and
> - $\pi_n(f,x):\pi_n(X,x)\to\pi_n(Y,f(x))$ is an isomorphism for all $x\in X$ and $n\geq 1.$

Here $\pi_0(X)$ denotes the set of path-components of $X$ without any choice of basepoint, so the first condition is non-vacuous even if $X$ is empty.

Comment: Why there is some $x$ in $X$ in your second $\bullet$ if $X=\emptyset$? Why is it also non-vacuous ?

Comment: The second condition is vacuous if $X$ is empty.  But when $X$ is empty, the first condition can only hold if $Y$ is also empty.

Comment: I do not follow where is the difference between the vacuousness of the first and of the second $\bullet$.

Comment: The second condition is stated "for all $x\in X$" and the first one is not.

Comment: So why it is necessary for the first $\bullet$ to omit for all $x\in X$ and in the second $\bullet$ not.

Comment: Also in the first $\bullet$ we do not know that $\pi_0(f)$ preserves the basepoint if $X\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: The whole point is that the first condition does not involve any basepoint, since we are taking $\pi_0(X)$ without any basepoint.